# How to pass a cookie value string array to the controller to get looped as PayPal Items

Tags: c#, arrays, cookies, paypal

I'm trying to pass my CookieCarts string array (containing shopping cart items) into my controller to get looped for my Paypal api.

**My View**

```
    var cookiecart = Server.UrlDecode(Request.Cookies["cookieCart"].Value);                     
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CookieCart, new { Value = cookiecart })
    Response.Write(cookiecart);


cookiecart:*[{"datetime":"2016-02-25 02:51:49","id":"749","typeid":"13","qty":1,"fullname":"The Matrix","image":"/Content/images/products/online-video.png","price":"69","sku":"MATRIX"}]*
```

**My Model**

```
 public string CookieCart { get; set; }
```

**My Controller**

```
    var cartArray = model.CookieCart;
    var cartArray = model.CookieCart;
    var itemArray = cartArray.Split(',');
    foreach (var t in itemArray)
    {item.name = itemArray[0]; }
```

when i quickwatch the data sent to the controller it looks like this:

```
cartArray displays: "[{\"datetime\":\"2016-02-25    02:51:49\",\"id\":\"749\",\"typeid\":\"13\",\"qty\":1,\"fullname\":\"The   Matrix\",\"image\":\"/Content/images/products/online-  video.png\",\"price\":\"69\",\"sku\":\"MATRIX\"}]"


item.name displays: *"[{\"datetime\":\"2016-02-25 02:51:49\""*
```

None of this is right. its so frustrating! How to convert a cookie array value into a C# array.

```
itemArray[0] should be:
itemArray[0][0] = datetime:"2016-02-25 02:51:49",
itemArray[0][1] = id:"749",
itemArray[0][2] = typeid:"13",
itemArray[0][3] = qty:1,
itemArray[0][4] = fullname:"The Matrix",
itemArray[0][5] = image:"/Content/images/products/online-video.png",
itemArray[0][6] = price:"69"
itemArray[0][7] = sku:"MATRIX"
```

:(

Comment: You're receiving data from a RESTful api which in this case, returns `Json` strings. I suggest looking into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figured it out. using JSON .Net:

**My Controller**

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies["cookieCart"];
cookieArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CookieCart>>
                        (Server.UrlDecode(cookie.Value));
```

**My Model**

```
public class CookieCart
{
    public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Typeid { get; set; }
    public string Qty { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
}
```

then i iterated the array items for PayPal:

```
        foreach (var cartitem in cookiecart)
        {
            item.name = cartitem.Fullname;
            item.currency = "USD";
            item.price = cartitem.Price;
            item.quantity = cartitem.Qty;
            item.sku = cartitem.Sku;
            var intPrice = Int32.Parse(cartitem.Price);
            subtotal = subtotal + intPrice;
        }
```